# Regex YouTube shorts url javascript python

Tags: javascript, python, regex, ajax, youtube

I am making a board where users can post text, photo, and YouTube video link
I am trying to generate embed url from different types of YouTube urls that user copy and paste.
thanks Stackoverflow gods, I almost got it but not 100%

my js regex for ajax call to api

```
const ytRegex = /^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$/
...
let video = $('#post-video').val();
if (ytRegex.test(video)) {
    video = $('#post-video').val();
} else {
    video = 0;
}
...
```

my python regex

```
video_receive = request.form['video_give']
video_id1 = re.findall("(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com)\/.+$", video_receive)
video_id2 = re.findall("(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtu\.?be)\/.+$", video_receive)
video_id3 = re.findall("(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com)\/(shorts).+$", video_receive)
    if video_id1 :
      link = video_receive.split("=")[1]
      embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"
      video = embed + link
    elif video_id2:
      link = video_receive.split("/")[3]
      embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"
      video = embed + link
    elif video_id3:
      link = video_receive.split("/")[4]
      embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"
      video = embed + link
    else:
      video = 1
```

I am targetting 3 example types of yt urls with variables video_id#

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjkVUaFhwno
2. https://youtu.be/BEkxOupf9Zc
3. https://youtube.com/shorts/UZsysDAUHAY?feature=share

1 is for desktop share url for yt video and yt shorts
2 is mobile share url for yt video
3 is mobile share url for yt shorts

In my python code,
`if video_id1` & `elif video_id2` works fine but problem arise after I added `elif video_id3`
when I test with `https://youtube.com/shorts/UZsysDAUHAY?feature=share`
my code stores `https://www.youtube.com/embed/share` into db
It seems like `if video_id1` is working on `video_id3` format. I assume this because the testing url has `=` before `share` and `if video_id1` has `.split("=")` condition.

when I delete `?feature=share` from the testing url, my web page give me error(POST...500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)) not even submitting to db due to ajax call error. but works with original testing url.

Please advise me where I am getting wrong with yt shorts url.

Comment: Can you just check for regex 3 before 1? Regex 1 would also match pattern 3

Comment: oh wow, just switching line of variable 3 and 1 made this work. I did not realize there is an order. Wow so simple but I would never get this without your help Thank you so much. @Sayse How can I credit your answer when you helped me with comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you use for the first pattern will also match your shorts urls, simply just check for pattern 3 first.